# How to open a SharePoint page without the master page?

Tags: 2010

How can I open an existing SharePoint 2010 page (like for example EditForm.aspx) without the master page (without the menus on top and the Links on the left) (exactly like if I open it with IsDlg=1, but I don't want it a dialog box).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just append IsDlg=1 to your URL. The open in dialog is not controlled by the IsDlg=1 parameter.

To avoid opening the edit/view form of a list item in a dialog, you can also set the "Launch forms in a dialog" setting in the list settings -> advanced settings to "no".

Answer (score 2):

You can set the master page to be a basic master page such as minimal.master instead of the v4.master page. (I think there is also one called basic.master or base.master for dialog boxes, although I couldn't find it!).

Normally the dialog box would use the normal v4.master and use CSS to hide the unwanted elements, which have the CSS class "s4-notdlg". So another way, if you want to use v4.master, is to make sure you have a CSS rule for s4-notdlg that makes it visibility:none.

Answer (score 0):

Bender has the simplest solution. IsDlg controls just the formatting of the page, not the page's presentation in a dialog.